# jQuery number animation for 3,450.86

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate number using jQuery. My number is 3,450.86 when i'm trying to animate this number i can able to animate 3,450 this number only not getting decimal values.

Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code once, if you like to add counterUp library in your code then use below code. Thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('span').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<span class=".integers">12345</span><br><br>
<span class=".floats">123.45</span><br><br>
<span class=".numbers-with-commas">12,345.00</span>
```